# @Scheduled with cron expression stop working suddenly

Tags: java, spring, cron, scheduled-tasks

I know this question repeat itself but i have trying all the suggestions and nothing work.
I'm using spring 1.4.3.
And I'm using elastic beanstalk, such that my dev EC2 instance type: t2.small compare to prod that is EC2 instance type: t2.large

the job i was trying work till today and suddenly it stops with not ERROR or anything...(it's not only this job is all the jobs i have in my project)

My config is:

```
  @Configuration
 @EnableAsync
 @EnableScheduling
  public class AppConfig{

  @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
public Executor taskScheduler() {
    return Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);
   }
}
```

The job I'm trying is very simple:

```
 @Service
open class TestProcessing {
private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.javaClass)
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)
fun startProcessing2(){
        logger.info("Test2 Job")
     }

 }
```

my main is:

```
  @SpringBootApplication(exclude = EndpointMBeanExportAutoConfiguration.class)
  public class ApiServerApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SpringApplicationBuilder(ApiServerApplication.class).run(args);
   }
}
```

The post request:

```
     @ResponseBody
     @RequestMapping(
  path = arrayOf("", "/"),
  method = arrayOf(RequestMethod.POST),
  consumes = arrayOf(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE))
    fun insertDispenserRecordsList(@RequestHeader(name = "xg-BAddress", required = false) reporter: String?,
                             @Valid @RequestBody dispenserRecords: DispenserRecordsList<DispenserRecordInput>,
                             bindingResult: BindingResult): ResponseEntity<*> {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        throw exception(bindingResult)
          }
        dispenserRecordsService.insertDispenserRecordsList(reporter, dispenserRecords.dispenserRecords)
       return ResponseEntity<Any>(HttpStatus.OK)
```

}

the funny part is that job is working on production and on local but not on dev, the different between them is that on dev every second there is a post request...
It looks like this:

```
    2018-04-09 23:29:17.080  WARN 22763 --- [io-8080-exec-53] c.h.u.q.RequestStatisticsInterceptor     : [Time: 454 ms] [Queries: 3] POST /v1/dispensers/records
    2018-04-09 23:29:17.316  WARN 22763 --- [io-8080-exec-49] c.h.u.q.RequestStatisticsInterceptor     : [Time: 213 ms] [Queries: 3] POST /v1/wristbands/records
    2018-04-09 23:29:20.396  WARN 22763 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.h.u.q.RequestStatisticsInterceptor     : [Time: 180 ms] [Queries: 3] POST /v1/wristbands/records
    2018-04-09 23:29:21.115  WARN 22763 --- [io-8080-exec-30] c.h.u.q.RequestStatisticsInterceptor     : [Time: 206 ms] [Queries: 3] POST /v1/wristbands/records
    2018-04-09 23:29:21.284  WARN 22763 --- [io-8080-exec-33] c.h.u.q.RequestStatisticsInterceptor     : [Time: 215 ms] [Queries: 3] POST /v1/wristbands/records
    2018-04-09 23:29:21.927  WARN 22763 --- [io-8080-exec-61] c.h.u.q.RequestStatisticsInterceptor     : [Time: 251 ms] [Queries: 3] POST /v1/wristbands/records
    2018-04-09 23:29:22.667  WARN 22763 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] c.h.u.q.RequestStatisticsInterceptor     : [Time: 159 ms] [Queries: 3] POST /v1/wristbands/records
    2018-04-09 23:29:25.203  WARN 22763 --- [io-8080-exec-44] c.h.u.q.RequestStatisticsInterceptor     : [Time: 265 ms] [Queries: 3] POST /v1/wristbands/records
    2018-04-09 23:29:27.754  WARN 22763 --- [io-8080-exec-28] c.h.u.q.RequestStatisticsInterceptor     : [Time: 213 ms] [Queries: 4] POST /v1/wristbands/records
    2018-04-09 23:29:28.160  WARN 22763 --- [io-8080-exec-64] c.h.u.q.RequestStatisticsInterceptor     : [Time: 219 ms] [Queries: 3] POST /v1/wristbands/records
    2018-04-09 23:29:31.733  WARN 22763 --- [io-8080-exec-13] c.h.u.q.RequestStatisticsInterceptor     : [Time: 189 ms] [Queries: 3] POST /v1/wristbands/records
    2018-04-09 23:29:32.212  WARN 22763 --- [io-8080-exec-37] c.h.u.q.RequestStatisticsInterceptor     : [Time: 363 ms] [Queries: 3] POST /v1/wristbands/records
    2018-04-09 23:29:35.390  WARN 22763 --- [io-8080-exec-12] c.h.u.q.RequestStatisticsInterceptor     : [Time: 374 ms] [Queries: 3] POST /v1/wristbands/records
    2018-04-09 23:29:36.167  WARN 22763 --- [io-8080-exec-59] c.h.u.q.RequestStatisticsInterceptor     : [Time: 174 ms] [Queries: 3] POST /v1/wristbands/records
    2018-04-09 23:29:37.918  WARN 22763 --- [io-8080-exec-34] c.h.u.q.RequestStatisticsInterceptor     : [Time: 188 ms] [Queries: 3] POST /v1/wristbands/records
    2018-04-09 23:29:41.144  WARN 22763 --- [io-8080-exec-24] c.h.u.q.RequestStatisticsInterceptor     : [Time: 199 ms] [Queries: 3] POST /v1/wristbands/records
    2018-04-09 23:29:43.337  WARN 22763 --- [io-8080-exec-34] c.h.u.q.RequestStatisticsInterceptor     : [Time: 192 ms] [Queries: 3] POST /v1/wristbands/records
    2018-04-09 23:29:44.361  WARN 22763 --- [io-8080-exec-48] c.h.u.q.RequestStatisticsInterceptor     : [Time: 176 ms] [Queries: 3] POST /v1/wristbands/records
    2018-04-09 23:29:45.624  WARN 22763 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] c.h.u.q.RequestStatisticsInterceptor     : [Time: 352 ms] [Queries: 3] POST /v1/wristbands/records
    2018-04-09 23:29:46.094  WARN 22763 --- [io-8080-exec-37] c.h.u.q.RequestStatisticsInterceptor     : [Time: 186 ms] [Queries: 3] POST /v1/wristbands/records
```

If you need more details please let me know...
Thank you for the help

Comment: the POST request you are talking about, Is it Asynchronous ???

Comment: @Rezwan no its not

Comment: any solution or explanation that might cause this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Situation points that its because on dev every POST request is performing some task or call to any other external system that waits for its response.
One possible solution is to define timeout for POST request which should be less than @Sceduled time.
I had same problem for POST request which get list of records from DB.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
ResponseEntity<?> add(@PathVariable String userId, @RequestBody Bookmark input) {
    this.validateUser(userId);

    return this.accountRepository
            .findByUsername(userId)
            .map(account -> {
                Bookmark result = bookmarkRepository.save(new Bookmark(account,
                        input.getUri(), input.getDescription()));

                URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder
                    .fromCurrentRequest().path("/{id}")
                    .buildAndExpand(result.getId()).toUri();

                return ResponseEntity.created(location).build();
            })
            .orElse(ResponseEntity.noContent().build());

}
```

This waits for response from service. In your case POST request must be waiting for response asynchronously, otherwise it must not be running in Prod or Local.

Comment: sorry i didn't understand the solution, i added the post request that happened, can you help me how should i change it to make it work?

Comment: where is the wait part?

Comment: add "spring.mvc.async.request-timeout=10000" in your application.properties file.

Comment: r u using Rest Template Bean for Rest Call??

Comment: no I'm not...
I'm using gradle and not mvc...what should i add instead of the mvc?

Comment: you mean xml configuration ?? can you show gradle code you r using

Comment: i mean my build is with gradle and not with mvc...im not sure if its matter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168675/discussion-between-rezwan-and-tal-shani).